# Color coding a single cell in list with jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, formatting

based on this jquery that worked, how do I change it to color code a single cell instead of the whole row? I also need 3 colors

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("td.ms-vb2").each( function () {

       if($(this).text() == "VALUE"){
       $(this).parent("tr").css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");
       //$(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");
       }      


    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("td .ms-vb2:contains('value')").css("color", "Red");
```

Or in your code, in if condition, try to use

```
$(this).css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");
```

Comment: it does not work (tried the second one)

Comment: do you have any issue to try the first one!!!

Comment: That i would have to change the whole code  and i am not able to, I have replaced the IF line and THIS line with your one single line and it does not work, if you could please post the whole code it would be better

Comment: ok, this code works with lists but when I applied it to the library 'Pages' it does not work, do I need to change something? the 'cell' of pages is still td.ms-vb2